# Google Chrome 4.0.249.89 not working

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, browser

I am running Google Chrome 4.0.249.89 and noticed a weird behavior with it. It loads but I get this error:

[image]

Notice that there is an absence of commonly used pages in the display itself and displays the error message instead.

Has google chrome ceased to function after a certain limit of bookmarks?

I have tried the `setup --rename-chrome-exe` trick which did not work. I just don't want to lose my bookmarks.

Comment: -1 for not having superuser on your bookmarks bar :P

Comment: @Kez: I am more of an SO user.... :P LOL!

Comment: Do you mean the most visited page icons in your NewTab interface? Or the  bookmarks, like on the toolbar under address bar?

Comment: I had to give up on Chrome for various reasons including that.  You get the same randomly appearing message in IE using the Chrome Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What may be an option, is to back up the `Bookmarks` file and then reinstall Chrome from scratch in case one of the files in your profile is corrupt.

1. Backup Bookmarks file from `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
2. Uninstall Chrome
3. Manually delete the folder `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome`
4. Reinstall Chrome
5. Copy the Bookmarks file back to `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

EDIT - in response to comment regarding installation of **BitDefender**:

Try this in BitDefender (expert mode):

1. Click Antivirus | Shield | Advanced Settings
2. Add Chrome to the Exclusions, 
   `C:\Documents and Settings\Tom\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

Comment: @Kez: Many thanks for your answer but unfortunately it did not work as suggested...there is something in there that is preventing it from working properly...

Comment: Hmm.  Any luck installing the beta version over the top instead?  http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/

Comment: @tommieb75 do you have tested to launch chrome between step 4 and 5?

Comment: @fluxtendu: Yes. I have tried to launch chrome between the two steps 4 and 5 and nothing happened, still got the same issue...am trying the beta and copy over my precious stuff to beta to see what happens...I'm taking a long shot here if there's any internal changes to preferences, bookmarks, etc...

Comment: I installed chrome beta....still the same thing...Bitdefender showed it as adding a new firewall rule to access it but no joy....

Comment: Install the new Dev release, since it's already at 5.0 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between bookmarks and most visited pages, that appear on New Tab page. First ones you can see on the toolbar right under the address bar (as in your image), the other ones are generated from the history of your browsing.

Bookmarks are stored in `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks`. Most visited pages are not stored, but generated from `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History*` files

My recommendation is that you should save your entire profile, i.e. `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` folder and copy it to safe location. Since it seems like Google Chrome crashes in your computer does not depend on your profile, you can try to recover your bookmarks/most-visited-pages on friend's computer. Meanwhile you can also try to fix the problem with Google Chrome:

1. Uninstall Google Chrome
2. Remove entirely this folder: `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome`
3. Search your registry for string "Chrome" and delete any related keys and values
4. Reboot
5. Update your antivirus database and scan your computer for viruses
6. Download fresh version of Google Chrome from http://www.google.com/chrome. Do not reuse old installer - it may be infected by a virus.
7. Install it and try running

If this still doesn't help, then the problem is way to complex and requires an attention of an IT professional (with remote control or similar). If you have such friends -- let them try to help. Hiring professional is typically quite expensive, I would then recommend using another browser or reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install any experimental addons that use the new Chrome process or history [experimental API's](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/03/experimental-extension-apis.html)?  These can change the behavior of the [new tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) or history functionality.

Perhaps you installed an add-on that's using these new API and it has broken the Chrome install until its uninstalled?

I'm struck that your error is with the new tab functionality and it follows closely the release of these experimental API's.

Answer (score 0):

1- It's just a simple trick which helps you save your bm every time . Enable sync in Google Chrome. 
Google has a way to kill specify crash function, not all your chrome . So, you won't lose your bookmark that easily :)
I've crashed dozen times because IDM's integration.